# pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html

Tags: html, pip, pytest

I have html report installed for pytest.

It was working fine until one day this error was thrown

> pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with " have html report installed for pytest" exactly - what did you install how? Does "html" show up in the list of plugins pytest prints when it starts?

Answer (score 27):

Use `pip list` to check if you have `pytest-html` installed. If not, install it using `pip install pytest-html`.

[pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) is a plugin for pytest, not part of pytest library.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Glad I helped !

Answer (score 4):

Please add *pytest-html* package from *pycharm*.
Make sure you have already installed plugin for html report.

Comment: This works for my case. Thank you!