# Selenium Pytest - Unrecognized argument html report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure, pytest-html

I created some test scripts using selenium python and they have been working okay. However, I have had trouble when I tried to generate an html report or an allure report.

I used the following command to try to generate a pytest html report: "`pipenv` run python `-m` pytest `xxx/test_xxxx.py --html=report.html`". However, I got the following error: "

```
ERROR: usage: __main__.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html
  inifile: None
  rootdir: C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx"
```

. I had installed the `pytest-html` plugin using pip install `pytest-html`, so I am not sure what I have been doing wrong.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that did not work. I also tried the following links (among others):

- [pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=report.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955700/pytest-error-unrecognized-arguments-html-report-html)
- [generate html and json reports for selenium python automation test using pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71029796/generate-html-and-json-reports-for-selenium-python-automation-test-using-pytest)

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. Since I am using pipenv to run my tests, I would have to install the dependencies through pipenv as well. So for the html and allure reports, the full commands would be as follows:

```
pipenv run pip install allure-pytest
pipenv run pip install pytest-html
```

After trying this, I ran my previous commands and I no longer got the issue.